# Type Properties In Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am unable to get what is 'Type Properties' defined in Swift. I follow below link but unable to get what is exactly.

[Type Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254)

I am curious what is the need of Type properties & where we can use them in our code.

Comment: Did you just report your own question? Perhaps you should delete your question, if you think that it's duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define properties of a type to either be associated with the type itself (these are called Type properties), but you can also define properties to be associated with a specific instance of that type.

Type properties are usually used when you want to define something that is the same for each instance of a type and hence you shouldn't be able to change it specifically for each instance and you should be able to access it using the type itself without having to create an instance.

You can declare type properties using the `static` keyword.

```
class MyClass {
    static let typeProperty = "Type"
    let instanceProperty = "Instance"
}
```

You can access the type property from the type itself:

```
let typeProp = MyClass.typeProperty
```

But to access an instance property, you need to create an instance of the type:

```
let instance = MyClass()
let instanceProp = instance.instanceProperty
```